# Advice for Relationship between Album, Artist, Track and Label an (music stuff)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

An album may have many Artists like this [release](https://open.spotify.com/album/4UpQlX9ApQ15vulTUJepwp).

But an album may have only one artist like [this](https://open.spotify.com/album/4TU8d9DGafZZiyN7peC4sl).

A Label has many Albums like [this](https://www.discogs.com/label/769094-Armada-4).

I'm little confused about relationships, on the other hand an album has many tracks! I am confused about everything because the other side there is a Label (company for sign up music) table and Label has many albums!

Some advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to use the following schema:

#### artist

- id
- name

#### album

- id
- name

#### label

- id
- name

#### track

- id
- name
- length

#### albums_has_artists

- id
- album_id
- artist_id

#### label_has_albums

- id
- label_id
- album_id

#### album_has_tracks

- id
- album_id
- track_id

And if `album_has_artists rows > 1` => show "Various Artists".

Comment: Thanks, it's good you noted about "Various Artists" cuze i have a plan for it and another type of release is , Single and Eps, one track = single , two or four track (sometimes) is Eps...

Comment: another question, why you did a many to many relationship between Album and Track? a album may have many tracks right? but how Track can belongtoMany release at the same time ? i'm a bit confused

Comment: Yes, I did it because an album has many tracks. How do you see a release? Is it the same as an album? Otherwise I would create a new table `release` and `release_has_tracks`. Another solution would be to add a `release_type` column to the `album` table where you can store a value if the album is a single release, EP release or a full album.

Comment: @Mwthreex Please accept this answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

I think following example will help you understand relationship between Album, Artist, Track and Label.Consider a models given below

```
class Label extends Model
{
    public function Albums()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Albums::class, 'album_id', 'id')->select('id') // select will contain whatever data you want from album );
    }
}

class Albums extends Model
{
    public function Artists()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Artists::class, 'artist_id', 'id')->select('id') // select will contain whatever data you want from table artists);
    }

    public function Tracks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Tracks::class, 'track_id', 'id')->select('id') // select will contain whatever data you want from table tracks);
    }
}
```

even if only one album have many Artists it will be considered in hasMany relationship.

Comment: Correct. Has Many is a misnomer because it really means has zero or many.

Comment: Thanks. i think there is mistake about Tracks method, cuze this belongTo Album model i think

Comment: @Mwthreex  Try to understand this:   Each Albums has many tracks so in Albums model Albums hasMAny relation to tracks . Now consider Model Tracks :     class Tracks extends Model
{
    public function Albums()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Albums::class, 'album_id', 'id')->select('id') // select will contain whatever data you want from album );
    }
}